# ¿Como activar/desactivar una lista de botones "Bootstrap Toggle" desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, botón

Quiero desactivar la lista de botones de este tipo que tengo en mi pantalla, pero me da error, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

El modo para desactivarlo lo estoy sacando de la [api del plugin](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/).

```js
$(document).on('click', '#deshabiltar', function() {
        var toogles = $('#toggle.botonEstado');
        for (var i = 0; i < toogles.length; i++) {
            toogles[i].bootstrapToggle('disable');
        }
});


$(document).on('click', '#habilitar', function() {
        var toogles = $('#toggle.botonEstado');
        for (var i = 0; i < toogles.length; i++) {
            toogles[i].bootstrapToggle('enable');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input id="toggle" class="botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">


<button type="button" id="deshabiltar" class="btn btn-primary">Deshabiltar</button>

<button type="button" id="habilitar" class="btn btn-primary">Habilitar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario tratar de recorrer con for los checkbox, buscando con jquery puedes apuntar a todos ellos.

Solo eh modificado tu script js:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#deshabiltar', function() {
        $(".toggle").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});


$(document).on('click', '#habilitar', function() {
        $(".toggle").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">
<input class="toggle botonEstado" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="">


<button type="button" id="deshabiltar" class="btn btn-primary">Deshabiltar</button>

<button type="button" id="habilitar" class="btn btn-primary">Habilitar</button>
```

---

Nota: Por buena practica, no es muy recomendable manejar los elementos de html con el mismo nombre de id, puedes manejarlos con la misma clase sin problema

Comment: Genial, solo quedaría el como colocar el cursor del estilo de `not-allowed`.